JPA returning same object multiple times instead of expected objects
I have this entity class
// package and imports

@Entity
@IdClass(WorkflowRouteId.class)
@Table(name = "workflowroute")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WorkflowRoute {
    @Column(name = "inputmoduleid", nullable = false)
    private UUID inputModuleId;
    @Column(name = "outputmoduleid", nullable = false)
    private UUID outputModuleId;
    @Column(name = "instance", nullable = false)
    private short instance;
    @Column(name = "waitall", nullable = false)
    private boolean waitAll;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "workflowid", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Workflow workflow;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "routeid", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Route route;
}

Its @IdClass
// package and imports

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@Setter
public class WorkflowRouteId implements Serializable {
    private UUID workflow;
    private UUID route;
}

And the repository
// package and imports

@Repository
public interface WorkflowRouteRepository extends JpaRepository<WorkflowRoute, WorkflowRouteId> {
    @Query("SELECT wr FROM WorkflowRoute wr WHERE wr.workflow.id = :workflowId")
    List<WorkflowRoute> findWorkflowRouteByWorkflowId(UUID workflowId);
    List<WorkflowRoute> findAllByWorkflowId(UUID workflowId);
    List<WorkflowRoute> findAllByWorkflow_Id(UUID workflowId);
    List<WorkflowRoute> findAllByWorkflow(Workflow workflow);
}

As you can see by the names of the repository methods, they all do the same. But none of them return the expected results.
I expect to get 8 distinct different WorkflowRoute objects instead I get the the first one 'cloned' 8 times. Of course I have checked the DB and there's no mistake there. What is interesting to me is that the count of expected objects always matches the count of actually returned objects, but like I said the returned objects are all the same. Do you guys have any hints/tips on what I have done wrong?
(Edit) Here's what I have in the DB
Columns: workflowid routeid inputmoduleid outputmoduleid instance waitall
Data:
"4e97b14c-83ec-4047-9b1a-2a38569f6a4e"
"e0147698-655d-4475-9198-24bbdceed685"
"b06f0447-df6d-4379-b273-7302fcfe58c4"
"d8aba9c5-fa6b-4eb4-bbd9-286c33baa17b"
1
false
"4e97b14c-83ec-4047-9b1a-2a38569f6a4e"
"e0147698-655d-4475-9198-24bbdceed685"
"d8aba9c5-fa6b-4eb4-bbd9-286c33baa17b"
"5c4b95d0-f292-4cdb-b1b6-b3af2298f843"
2
false
"4e97b14c-83ec-4047-9b1a-2a38569f6a4e"
"e0147698-655d-4475-9198-24bbdceed685"
"5c4b95d0-f292-4cdb-b1b6-b3af2298f843"
"695e6514-edc0-4f44-a544-a847c6b8dd66"
3
false
"4e97b14c-83ec-4047-9b1a-2a38569f6a4e"
"e0147698-655d-4475-9198-24bbdceed685"
"695e6514-edc0-4f44-a544-a847c6b8dd66"
"8427116e-4426-43cb-93b5-bbb802e936fa"
4
false
"4e97b14c-83ec-4047-9b1a-2a38569f6a4e"
"e0147698-655d-4475-9198-24bbdceed685"
"8427116e-4426-43cb-93b5-bbb802e936fa"
"54fda010-db9b-4b0b-9daa-c9bf8bc2487f"
5
false
And here's what I get
"4e97b14c-83ec-4047-9b1a-2a38569f6a4e"
"e0147698-655d-4475-9198-24bbdceed685"
"b06f0447-df6d-4379-b273-7302fcfe58c4"
"d8aba9c5-fa6b-4eb4-bbd9-286c33baa17b"
1
false
"4e97b14c-83ec-4047-9b1a-2a38569f6a4e"
"e0147698-655d-4475-9198-24bbdceed685"
"b06f0447-df6d-4379-b273-7302fcfe58c4"
"d8aba9c5-fa6b-4eb4-bbd9-286c33baa17b"
1
false
and 3 more times of this.

Are you saying the list of WorkflowRoute objects should all be unique? If so, have you tried changing the query from your Query annotation to something like this?
SELECT DISTINCT wr FROM WorkflowRoute wr WHERE wr.workflow.id = :workflowId

Also, you could try changing the response from a List to a Set if you're expecting rows to be unique, since Sets inherently eliminates duplicates. Perhaps that will work as well.
Set<WorkflowRoute> findWorkflowRouteByWorkflowId(UUID workflowId);


Thanks for trying to help, but that wasn't the problem I had. I updated the question. Hope it's more clear now. Sorry for the lack of info.
